# oracle 10g contains clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g, contains

I am new to SQL. I am trying to write a query which requires contains operator. I am looking at many examples for the contains clause, but they seem different than what I need to use. I want a divide operator(relational algebra) equivalent in sql.

a sample of what I am doing is :

Give the students names who are enrolled for computer architecture course and have satisfied all its prerequisites. I have a prereq table and a course table which lists all courses taken by student

so what I ultimately want is
(get all courses taken by a student) contains (get all prerequisits)

for what exactly shall I look for for sql equivalent of divide operation in relational algebra?

Comment: `contains` is an Oracle Text function.  I'm pretty certain that's not what you're after.  My guess is that you want `minus` but perhaps you want `intersect`.  If you can explain in words what you want to be returned, that would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by comparing counts.

```
select s.StudentName
from StudentCourses s, PrereqCourses p
where s.CourseId = p.CourseId
group by s.StudentName
having count(*) = (select count(*) from PrereqCourses)
```

See: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_patterns_relational_division.htm